# Can we log mapreduce programs using logback.xml?

Tags: java, xml, hadoop, slf4j

Is it possible to log a mapreduce program using slf4j logback.xml ? I have tried logging a mapreduce program using logback.xml.But nothing had logged into console.

```
My logback.xml:
===============
<configuration>
<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
<!-- encoders are assigned the type
ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder by default -->
<encoder>
<pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
</encoder>
</appender>
<root level="debug">
<appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
</root>
</configuration>
```

Can anyone suggest me on this issue ...

Thanks,in advance.

Comment: Make sure hadoop is able to find logback configs!